# unexpected behavior regarding bash file reading EOL EOF

Tags: bash, file-io

I am experiencing some trouble while reading a file in a bash script.

Here is the file I am trying to read :

```
--------------- (not in the file)
123.234 231.423
1223.23 132.134

--------------- (not in the file)
```

In this file, the 4 numbers are on two different lines and there is a line left blank at the end of the file. There is no "space" character at the end of each line.

When I am trying to read this file using this script :

```
for val in $(cat $myFile)
do
   echo "$val ";
done
```

I do have the following result :

```
123.234 
231.423 

1223.23 
 32.134
```

When I add a space character after the variable, it erases the beginning of the last number

```
for val in $(cat ~/Windows/Trash/bashReadingBehavior/trashFile.out)
do
    echo "$val  ";
done
```

output :

```
123.234  
231.423  

1223.23  
  2.134
```

In fact, characters added after the last numbers are written at the beginning of the last numbers. I assume this is a behavior caused by an invisible character such as carriage return or something like this but I can't figure out how to solve this issue.

Comment: You mention Windows. Do you get `^M` characters if you do `cat -vte file`? You can "clean" it with `dos2unix file`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your input file has DOS line endings. When you execute

```
echo "$val  "
```

the value of `$val` ends with a carriage return, which when printed moves the cursor to the beginning of the line before the final two spaces are printed, which can overwrite whatever is already on the line.

You should use the following code to read from this file (don't iterate over the output of `cat`):

```
while read; do
    REPLY=${REPLY%$'\r'}  # Remove the carriage return from the line
    for val in $REPLY; do
        echo "$val"
    done
done
```

Iterating over a line with a `for` loop like I show isn't really recommended either, but it is OK in this case if the line read from the file and stored in `REPLY` is known to be a space-separated list of numbers.